# Nulls are located at all primes on the real axis?

Tags: prime-numbers, roots

This [page](https://imaginary.org/gallery/sunset-at-the-sea-of-primes) claims "a complex function, whose nulls are located at all primes on the real axis"

$$f(z) = \left| 2 - \sum\limits^\infty_{k=1} \frac{1}{k} \frac{e^{2 \pi i z}-1}{ e^{2 \pi i z / k}-1} \right|$$

Does this formula have a name? Is the claim true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a trick!

Hint: Which values of $z$ make

$$
e^{2\pi i z} - 1 = 0
$$

and

$$
e^{2\pi i z/k} - 1 \neq 0
$$

for all integers $k \geq 2$, $k \neq z$?

Comment: The first is the integers, right? I guess the second one would go to such integers which aren't divisible by any positive integer which does sound like primes except of course if $k=z$ and $k=1$ -- what happens there? Complex powers are confusing :)

Comment: Right on the first one. For the second there was a typo, I meant $k=2$ When $k=1$ something different happens: the fraction reduces to $1$. And indeed, when $k=z$ it reduces as well. These two observations of yours will lead to the proof.

Comment: If `k=z` or `k=1` and `z` is integer then it doesn't reduce but it becomes $0\over 0$ ...?

Comment: Try taking a limit in $z$ instead.